# K-means clustering exam question

Tags: self-study, k-means

I have an exam on the k-means algorithm and clustering and I was wondering if anyone knows how to figure out this sample exam question. My teachers are hopeless to provide any information on how to solve this question. Thank you

[image]

Comment: You must specify what you want us to help you with. Questions like "solve this for me" will likely be closed, and you should also use the self-study tag. Apart from that, it seems pretty straight-forward to me. In (i) you are given the equation to use, (ii) follows from (i). (iii) may be tricky to parse, but once you get it it is also straight-forward; is this the one you are having problems with?

Comment: +1 to @TommyL's comment. In addition, I'd counsel against writing that your teachers are "hopeless". Many people here also teach and may be put off if you sound like a complainer.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that (ii) has two possible interpretations: 1) Determine which of the points, $p_i$, for $i=1,\ldots,5$, is closest to $s_1$ and which of the points $p_i$, for $i=1,\ldots,5$, is closest to $s_2$; or 2) Ascribe each point, $p_i$, for $i=1,\ldots,5$, to the seed point, $s_1$ or $s_2$, that it is closest to. From the point-of-view of the algorithm, 2) would make more sense, but if the point is to teach you how to use the Euclidean norm in the K-means algorithm, 1) would make more sense.

Comment: Hi, I would like to add that I did not mean to sound like a 'complainer' and I did not mean to insult anyone. I just needed someone to help explain to me the process of solving this question in plain english since my teacher did not provide any resources or information on solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your teachers' defense, the question sounds fairly self-explanatory. If you can pinpoint which part is causing you the trouble, I can be more specific. In any case, to give graphical intuition, have a look at this figure (from [Bishop's book](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Pattern_Recognition_and_Machine_Learning.html?id=kTNoQgAACAAJ)) below:

**(a)** The blue and red crosses in subplot (a) are the seeds (**s1** and **s2**) that your teacher gives.

**(b)** This corresponds to your subquestions **i** and **ii**, you first calculate the distances of all green points to the red and blue crosses (your initial guesses s1 and s2) and then paint each point as blue or red depending on whether they are closer to **s1** or **s2**. As an additional point, here your teacher also asks you to give the points that are the closest to the cluster centres.

**(c)** This is subquestion iii, based on how you painted the points in the previous step, you (re)calculate your cluster centres (s1 and s2) by taking the average of all  blue and red points separately.

**(d to i)** When you repeat the steps i to iii (given in your question) a sufficient number of times, you end up with better cluster centres that partition your green points into distinct red and blue groups.

[image]